# non-intersecting families of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Given $V$, a vector space over a finite field $F$ of size $k$, if $\dim(V)=m$, and $r$ divides $m$, there exists a family of $r$-dimensional subspaces, whose size is equal to $(k^m-1)/(k^r-1)$ and such that the intersection of any pair of subspaces in the family is equal to the singleton $\{0\}$. Thus, there is a family of nonintersecting $r$-dimensional subspaces of size $\omega(k^{m/r})$, provided that $r$ divides $m$.

Does the above claim remain true if we skip the divisibility assumption?

Comment: If $r$ does not divide $m$, then $(k^m-1)/(k^r-1)$ is not an integer (e.g., $k=5$, $m=3$, $r=2$, you get $124/24$), so what would "whose size is equal to..." mean in that case? (P.S., is "size" the cardinality, or the dimension?)

Comment: Do you mean $\omega(k^{m/r})$, rather than the $\omega(k^{m-r})$ attained for $r|m$?  (Note too that if $r < m < 2r$ then any two $r$-subspaces intersect so the family cannot be larger than 1.)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to mean ω(k^(m-r)). On the other hand, I am interested in the cases where r is very much smaller than m, and for which the above argument does not matter.